# Explain complicated code regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Recently I came across some code that is supposed to match these arrays try as I might I could not get all the pieces of the puzzle together to make sense

```
validateSequence([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) === true
validateSequence([1,2,3,4,5,8,7,8,9]) === false
validateSequence([2,4,6,8,10]) === true
validateSequence([0,2,4,6,8]) === true
validateSequence([1,3,5,7,9]) === true
validateSequence([1,2,4,8,16,32,64]) === false
validateSequence([0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]) === false
```

Here is the code that would validate it:

```
function validateSequence(x) {
  return !!x.reduce(function(a, v, i, arr){
    return (arr.length - 1 == i) ? a : a + (arr[i+1] - v) + ',';
  }, '').match(/^(\d+,)\1*$/);
}
```

for example what are the two !! before x.reduce and how does it work?

Comment: Is your question about the [double bang](http://stackoverflow.com/q/784929/2679750) or the RegExp?

Comment: more general how does this whole code work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *RegExp* `/^(\d+,)\1*$/` means

1. `^` From the beginning of the string
2. `(\d+,)` match any number of digits (`0`..`9`) followed by a comma `,`. Remember this.
3. `\1` match everything that follows this if it is exactly the same as what we saw in 2
4. If we've reached the end of the *String*, the pattern is a match

---

Next the following,

```
x.reduce(function(a, v, i, arr){ /*...*/}, '');
```

1. Create `''` as an initial condition
2. On an *Array* `x`, iterate over every item calling the function with the following parameters

   - `a` accumulator, the previous returned value (or the initial condition for first invocation)
   - `v` the item at the current iteration
   - `i` the index at the current iteration
   - `arr` the *Array* `.reduce` was called on (i.e. `x`, the `this` of `.reduce`)

---

So what is `return (arr.length - 1 == i) ? a : a + (arr[i+1] - v) + ','` doing?

Lets re-write it as an `if..else` and comment in what is happening

```
if (arr.length - 1 == i)   // if this is the last item in the array
    return a;              // return the accumulator (what we generated last invocation)
else                       // otherwise
    return a +             // return the accumulator AND
        (arr[i + 1] - v) + // the difference between this item and the next item AND
        ',';               // a comma
```

---

Finally, the last bit we need to understand is `!!`. This is just shorthand for converting

- A *truthy thing* (e.g. any object `[]`, non-empty string etc) to `true`
- A *falsy thing* (e.g. `null`, *RegExp* did not match) to `false`

This is being applied to the result of the *RegExp* so it basically means, if we found a match return `true`, otherwise `false`.

---

This explained, it is a **very convoluted** way to do the following

```
function validateSequence(seq) {
    var delta = seq[1] - seq[0],
        i;
    // some `.length` test here?
    for (i = 2; i < seq.length; ++i)
        if (seq[i - 1] + delta !== seq[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

I would not recommend using the method you provided.

Comment: S.so let me get this strait the what exactly is the accumulator its somehow the difference between previous and next item and is returned how come it stays the same even after in the termany operator(if else)it gets plused (arr[i + 1] - v) + ',';

Comment: @AaronRabinowitz The accumulator is the previous return value. E.g. if the last iteration `return`ed `"4,"`, the `a` in the current iteration is `"4,"`. If you then return `a + "6,"`, the `a` in the next iteration would therefore be `"4,6,"`. If we then had run out of items to iterate, `"4,6,"` would be the ultimate returned value of `.reduce`

Answer (score 1):

`!!` is known as the "double-bang" or "not-not" operator and is used to coerce an object into a boolean. See [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

`reduce` is an enumerator. It will execute the callback once for each element in the array. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

The function is looping through the array and will return true only if the each successive element in the array increases by the same integer value over the previous one.

Comment: Hint: Remove the !! from the return value and observe the output.